# How to create popup UIPickerView in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have an app where I want the user to submit lots of data (think registration form). Instead of having 10 picker views on the screen I would like to have 10 textfields, and when selected, a UIPickerView popups on the screen. When the data is selected, the UITextField displays the option that was selected in the UIPickerView.

Here is my attempt after looking at some code samples on line for swift and objective-c implementation:

```
partial class ContactController : UIViewController{
    UIPickerView ContactTypePicker = new UIPickerView();
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        ContactTypePicker.Hidden = true;
        List<string> data = {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
        ContactTypePicker.Model = new ListPickerModel(data);


        ContactTextField.ShouldBeginEditing = ((textField) => {
            ContactTypePicker.Hidden = false;
            return true;
        });

}
// generic picker class
public class ListPickerModel : UIPickerViewModel{
    List<string> _items;

    public ListPickerModel(List<string> items){
        _items = items;
    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView picker){
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint GetRowsInComponent (UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        return _items.Count;
    }

    public override string GetTitle (UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        return _items [(int)row].Description;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is looking pretty reasonable. What's the current issue? You need to implement `Selected(UIPickerView picker, Int32 row, Int32 component)` in your ListPickerModel to capture the selection. I would also add a `UIView` when you display the picker to dim the background (like a `UIAlertController` does).

Comment: @user3470987 :  So, how did it go ? Does it work well in the end ?